# Read an mdb (ms access) file without using ODBC

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe2

I would like to know if it's possible to read a .mdb file **without** the use of ODBC.

I need to write a Delphi application that reads 2 columns from a mdb file and writes those columns in a postgreSQL database.

Is there a trick, Delphi component or method that I can use that does not depend on ODBC.
*(For some reason ODBC on my devel-laptop is broken)*.

If need be I can also use Delphi 2007, and I even have a version of Delphi 1,2 and 3 somewhere as well.

Comment: Seems like it would be time better spent to fix ODBC on your machine than re-architecting your solution.

Comment: Use ADO.   It can access to a MDB using Jet 4.0. More efficient than ODBC.

Comment: @JohnFx, just started with it today. Ended up using ADO, and after 2 minutes of fiddling and it worked. Forgot that ADO does not depend on ODBC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ADODB. It is part of Delphi 2007, at least. It does not depend on ODBC or BDE: it uses OleDB/ADO instead.

Answer (score 1):

long *long* ago, there was Data Access Objects DAO, [but it appears that these are deprecated (all the way at the bottom)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx). Still, with a bit of luck you could still find documentation for it and use it.